# syntax specification for socket.io API

Tags: javascript, syntax, socket.io

sorry if this is a basic question, but I am trying to read the Socket.io API reference at [Socket.io](http://socket.io/docs/client-api/) and it seems to be specified in a unfamiliar syntax specification. for example, I can sort of guess what the below means, but would like it if there was a pointer to how to read the spec.

```
IO(url:String, opts:Object):Socket
```

and

```
IO#protocol
```

etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is a non-Javascript syntax.  I don't know why they use it - apparently written by someone who likes how some other language specifies things and doesn't care or doesn't realize that people who only know Javascript won't understand this syntax.  `socket.io` has great code - not great documentation.  The syntax is similar to something used by [ActionScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActionScript).

In a nutshell:

```
IO(url:String, opts:Object):Socket
```

Function (or probably constructor) named `IO`.

Takes two arguments.  One is described as a "url" and is of type string.  The other is described as "opts" and is of type Object.  The constructor returns a Socket object.

```
IO#protocol
```

The `protocol` method of an object that the `IO` constructor returns.  Don't ask me why in the world they use a `#` here to delineate since that has zero origin in Javascript.

Comment: Thanks jfriend. I kind of see that logic, but it would be nice to see a formal description of the specification syntax, otherwise you have to keep looking at code examples to be sure you're using it right

Comment: @user1936097 - yeah I agree.  I don't know why they do it this way.  It's quite odd.